# Timezone confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime, timezone

I have a form that allows users to select a start and an end date. The start and end dates will always be in entered with PST timezone. When saving the start and end dates I convert them to UTC and store them in a database.

The Web Server has a component that checks against these dates and resides in an EST timezone. I can't wrap my head around dates.

A simplified explanation:

- Data entered in **PST**.
- Stored in DB in **UTC**.
- Web Server hosted in **EST**

**How to correctly handle the PST timezone?**

Comment: So what is the issue?  As long as you save it UTC relative, you can always then adjust it back to PST before displaying it.

Comment: like I said datetime conversions confuse the heck out of me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Web Server is checking them in local time - meaning that the dates will be in EST, then to get your PST time, you would just need to subtract 3 hours.

However, since they are in UTC, you could just specify the time-zone when pulling from the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Pass culture info in to the DateTime e.g

```
DateTime A = (DateTime)DT["MyDate"];System.Globalization.CultureInfo CI =
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("YourCultureInfoCode");
```